# How can i change static color to RGB color/custom color?

Tags: vb.net, openxml-sdk

Im doing changing color of font in docx using openxml(vb.net).How can i change static color to RGB color/custom color?Below is my code,but doesnt function:

```
  Function AddColor(ByVal isFontColor As Boolean, ByVal text As String) As Run
    Dim runs = New Run()
    If isFontColor = True Then
        Dim props = New RunProperties()
    Dim fontColor = New Color With {.Val = CType(RGB(255, 200, 50), StringValue)}


        props.AppendChild(fontcolor)
        runs.Append(props)
    End If
    runs.Append(New Text(text))
    Return runs
    End Function
```

Original static color code:

```
   Function AddColor(ByVal isFontColor As Boolean, ByVal text As String) As Run
    Dim runs = New Run()
    If isFontColor = True Then
        Dim props = New RunProperties()
        Dim fontColor = New Color With
            {.Val = "red"} 'Dark red
        props.AppendChild(fontColor)
        runs.Append(props)
        'Set font color to default color
    Else isFontColor = False
        Dim props = New RunProperties()
        Dim fontColor = New Color With
                {.Val = “default"} 'Default Color
        props.AppendChild(fontColor)
        runs.Append(props)
    End If
    runs.Append(New Text(text))
    Return runs
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Eric, What is actually _not_ working? Can you post how you use the function? Cheers

Comment: actually what i means is i want to add color use RGB format, not like put the"purple" then get the purple, i want use rgb to add color

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand what you want. After reading up, it looks like you can pass the Hex color value to the parameter as a string and this should work! - Hopefully :)

I know I have used system.drawing.color reference which might not be ideal for you, but you could substitute my function with another to alculate the RGB to HEX of your own if you wish, but this should get the job done nicely..

```
Function AddColor(ByVal isFontColor As Boolean, ByVal text As String) As Run
    Dim runs = New Run()
    If isFontColor = True Then
        Dim props = New RunProperties()
        Dim fontColor = New Color With {.Val = RGB_To_HEX(255, 200, 50)}
        props.AppendChild(fontColor)
        runs.Append(props)
    End If
    runs.Append(New Text(text))
    Return runs
End Function

Function RGB_To_HEX(r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer, Optional a As Integer = 255) As String
    Dim c As System.Drawing.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b)
    Return c.ToArgb().ToString("X6")
End Function
```

Comment: Erm...i test just now , it no error but also come out nothing.